# ¿Cómo se podría hacer un login sin el comando "make:auth"?

Tags: laravel

Estoy indagando en la manera de hacer un login que me funcione y que tenga roles para que en base a ellos pueda acceder a unas vistas u a otras, la cosa es que no quiero hacerla por medio de `make:auth` pues no puedo ver qué pasa en cada momento con mis datos y ya hice una vez una aplicación con ese comando y al introducir los datos tan pronto me enviaba al dashboard como se desdecía y me mandaba de nuevo al login. ¿Alguien sabe de un tutorial que seguir para hacer un login sin el dichoso comando?

Comment: Puedes verificar este [tutorial](http://justlaravel.com/custom-authentication-laravel/) que esta muy detallado respecto a hacer un login personalizado en laravel.

Comment: Te sugiero reformular tu pregunta, pues no se ajusta al formato del sitio: la respuesta al título de la pregunta es un Sí o No, y además pedir tutoriales no es la idea, la idea es aportar y pedir CÓDIGO.

Comment: Entiendo, perdonen, sigo estando muy verde en este sitio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sí se puede, los pasos son algo largos como para colocarlos aqui.
Asi que simplemente te pasare un link muy bueno en donde lo realizan.

Este es un `post` de styde que es un buena pagina para aprender laravel.

este es el link https://styde.net/sistema-de-autenticacion-de-usuarios-en-laravel/

Comment: Muchas gracias, le echaré un ojo!

Comment: Aún así no es una buena idea responder con un enlace, es mejor siempre copiar el código aquí.